# How to customize column Font (size and style) by CSS class in DataTables pdf export?

Tags: datatables, pdfmake, datatable-buttons

can you guys show me how to change column font size and weight from the doc object in the *customize(doc)* function of the DataTables html5 PDF Export, using a css class.

I have a datatable where some columns must be bold and bigger than the others.

I have the following buttons definition (, which doesn't seem to work

```
$('.data-table').DataTable({
buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg" style="color: red"></i> PDF',
                titleAttr: 'Export to PDF',
                orientation: 'auto',
                className: 'btn btn-default',

                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 8;

                    doc.content[1].table.widths = ['*', 70, 70];

                    doc.styles['td.bigcol'] = {
                        fontSize: 16,
                        bold: true,
                    };

                    doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                        image: 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageStr,
                        fit: [80, 80]
                    });

                }
            }
        ]
});
```

my table is similar to this:

```
<table class="table data-table">
<thead>
<tr>
   <td class="bigCol">
            Some List of things
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="bigCol">On List 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bigCol">list 1 totals</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this goes on to like list 9. The table shows correctly on the browser window, but the pdf ayayayyy

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Im a bit confused thou.. on the accepted answer, where is 'rows' from ?? , they creating the doc object themselves there (if im not mistaken). The columns I want to style aren't necessarily in odd or even rows, they could be anywhere. I want to use the table from that doc parameter DataTables has created, and add the font styles to that and i thought having a common class would make it easier

Comment: I perhaps misread your question :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it.. with help from [This Post](http://www.edit5or.datatables.net/forums/discussion/29804/table-formatting-in-export#Comment_79997).

On the customize function, using Jquery I loop through each table's row, then each row's column to get the row index and column index, then use those indexes on the    table in the doc object to define a style for the column

```
doc.content[1].table.widths = ['*', 70, 70];

$('.data-table').find('tr').each(function(ix, row) {
    var index = ix;

    $(row).find('td').each(function(ind, column) {
        if ($(column).hasClass('bigCol')) {

            var fontSize = $(column).css('font-size').replace('px', '');

            doc.content[1].table.body[index][ind].style = {
                fontSize: parseInt(fontSize)
                bold: true
            };
        }
    });
});
```

The indexes on the DOM table are equivalent to ones on the doc's table body object